# Google Analytics SDK iOS 2.0b4 not sending any events

Tags: ios, google-analytics

It seems my base configuration of GATracker is working because I **am** able to see my device in the real-time section. However, even after a day or so of firing events via:

```
- (BOOL)send:(NSString *)trackType params:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

I have not seen any events under Engagement > Events > Overview.

I have verified:

- I can see traffic in the real-time pane ensuring base functionality
- the tracker object is non-nil when using above method
- the return value is `YES` for above method (i.e. it think's it was successfully queued at some point to send)
- I even implemented the `dispatch` call on `[GAI sharedInstance]` as a sanity check to ensure the events were getting flushed

I've heard reports the b3/b4 version of the 2.0 SDK have had issues sending events but not seeing any at all seems very unusual.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `send` and not `sendEventWithCategory`?

Comment: @Eduardo I'm in the process of migrating from using another analytics package (Mixpanel) and under that system one was able to just send an event name + a payload of K-V pairs related to the event which is pretty nice for flexibly sending misc. info along with an event. This (`send:params:`) seemed the most appropriate to just "re-wire" it up using GA. After inspecting the `sendEventWithCategory` I'm afraid I'll lose the ability to send arbitrary additional data along with my events.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics and Mixpanel are different tools and have different ways for sending data.

For Google Analytics events have only 4 fields:

- Category (string)
- Action (string)
- Label (string)
- Value (number)

Similarly Pageviews are another type of hit, but they only have 1 field, that is the page url. On mobile apps this is renamed to view instead but it works almost the same way.

These fields have names for reference but you can actually use them for whatever you want. You will be able to drill down from one to the other in the interface.

You can also "add" more fields by using [Custom Dimensions/Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/customdimsmets). If you set a page type custom dimension before the event, that custom dimension/metric will be bound to the event.

Note that it's important to understand and use the right scope for each custom dimension. If you set a session scope for example the only value you will see in GA is the last one set for that specific session, it overrides previous values. You have to configure these through the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue.

When I use:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker sendEventWithCategory:message
                                                withAction:nil
                                                 withLabel:nil
                                                 withValue:nil];
```

the result is logged right away.

but, when I use:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:message params:eventParams];
```

NO result gets logged at all